# Javascript/Typescript variable assignment is not happening for String.replace()

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

I know this might be a question that lots of people asked. My problem is that my variable is not getting assigned with the value which String.replace() returned.

Here is my code:

```
updateInputFiles(item: IExecutionModel, callback: (error: any, result: any) => void) {
    ...
    ...
        let args: string[] = field.fieldValue.split("#");
        for(let i = 0; i < args.length; i++) {
            //console.log("Inside loop: ", args[i]);
            if(args[i] === "executionId") {
                field.fieldValue = field.fieldValue.replace("#" + args[i] + "#", item.executionId).toString();
            }
            if(args[i] === "market"){
                this.getReference(args[i], job.application, item.market, (error, result) => {
                    if(result) {
                        for(let value of result.values) {
                            if(value.codeValue === item.market) {
                                field.fieldValue = field.fieldValue.replace("#" + args[i] + "#", value.resolvedValue).toString();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    ...
    ...
}
```

A sample field.fieldValue will be "/path/to/file/somename_#market#*something*#executionId#.txt"

Only **#executionId#** part got replaced, no matter how I tried I cannot replace **#market#**

Please help me out :)

Comment: Have you confirmed that you reach the innermost conditional of the `args[i] === market` if block?

Comment: It's difficult to say exactly what the problem is, as your example doesn't provide enough context or sample data to properly evaluate.  See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for some guidance.  That said, I suspect you'll find that the callback to `this.getReference` is being called after you're returning (or evaluating, logging, whatever-ing) `field.fieldValue`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like your `this.getReference` is an `async` function, as you are using the callback function to replace the `#market#` placeholder. Thus, there is a good chance that you are trying to use the replaced value, even before `this.getReference` is finished executing and returned the value, and thereby executing the callback.

It would be better if you promisify the call to `this.getReference`, which would be pretty easy to to do using TypeScript `async/await`.

Then you can refactor your code like this (untested):

```
async getReference(parameters):Promise //return type optional
{
    //do your magic and return a promise.
}

//invoke as:
await this.getReference(...)
          .then((error, result) => {
                if(result) {
                    for(let value of result.values) {
                        if(value.codeValue === item.market) {
                            field.fieldValue = field.fieldValue.replace("#" + args[i] + "#", value.resolvedValue).toString();
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
```

Reference links:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise
- https://www.dev6.com/TypeScriptAsyncandAwait

Comment: Awesome!! it worked as exactly what I was expecting!